# android [ java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.widget.Toolbar ]

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I created a tool bar in my list view activity. I used the following code for this:

```
public class Home extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://api-11hr.anovatesoft.com/v1/list";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER = "contactnumber";
    private static final String TAG_POSTAL_CODE = "postalcode";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";
    SessionManager session;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String apikey;
    private String status;
    GPSTracker gps;

    private Toolbar toolbar;                              // Declaring the Toolbar Object

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
        setActionBar(toolbar);                   // Setting toolbar as the ActionBar with setSupportActionBar() call

        // get action bar
      /*  ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);*/



        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                Home.this);

// Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog2.setTitle("Too quiet?");

// Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog2.setMessage("Follow your favourite merchants and see what deals they're launching at the 11th Hour!");



// Setting Positive "Yes" Btn
        alertDialog2.setPositiveButton("YES",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Write your code here to execute after dialog

                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });

        alertDialog2.show();


        Gps_func();


        // Session class instance
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // get user data from session
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();


        // apikey
        // Calling Application class (see application tag in AndroidManifest.xml)
        final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();

        //Set name and email in global/application context
        apikey = globalVariable.getApikey();


        latitude = globalVariable.getLatitude();
        longitude = globalVariable.getLongitude();
        status = globalVariable.getStatus();



        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem

                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                        .getText().toString();


                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Adds.class);

                in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);

                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    private void Gps_func() {

        gps = new GPSTracker(Home.this);

        // check if GPS enabled
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            // \n is for new line
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("tag", "Longitude:\n" + longitude + "\n Latitude: \n" + latitude);

        } else {
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();

            if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                // \n is for new line
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("tag", "Longitude:\n" + longitude + "\n Latitude: \n" + latitude);

            }
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Gps_func();
    }



    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait....");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler1 sh = new ServiceHandler1(apikey, latitude, longitude);


            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler1.POST);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);


            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        String gender = c.getString(TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER);
                        String postalcode = c.getString(TAG_POSTAL_CODE);


                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                        contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);


                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Home.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item1, new String[]{TAG_EMAIL,
            }, new int[]{
                    R.id.email,});

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

but when I run the application it give an error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.widget.Toolbar

please help me out for getting a tool bar

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
}
```

tool_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:elevation="4dp"

    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

list layout including tool_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Main ListView
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)


    -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post your `build.gradle`?

Comment: @KevinChris check my updated code plz..

Comment: post your layout including Toolbar

Comment: @SilentKnight i updated my code plz check it....

Answer (score 5):

This error means you want to cast the `Toolbar` of `R.id.tool_bar`. In your layout, `Toolbar` is `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` but in your `Home`, you want to cast it into `android.widget.Toolbar`. So, check your **import**s, make sure `Toolbar` you import is `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`.

P.S.:if it doesn't work, clean or rebuild your project.

Comment: it gives an error .........................
Error:(80, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Comment: Maybe you need to change your `ListActivity` to `AppCompatActivity` and change your `ListView`'s id

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31585385/how-to-extend-2-superclass-in-same-class-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Toolbar was included in support library. Till my knowledge toolbar should be imported from

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

not this

```
 android.widget.Toolbar
```

so i would like to request you to add toolbar from V7 support library as in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Android Support Libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

    }
```

Comment: ListActivity does't provide method to set android.support.v7.widget.toolbar
you have to  use AppCompatActivity and use this method setSupportActionBar(). if you need help how to use i can help you.

Comment: @Sanjeev please check this repo if it works for you. https://github.com/NewRajesh/Toolbar

Comment: yes please help me , when i tried to  extend AppCompatActivity  then it throws error  in my list adapter

Comment: if i comment my remainning code then i able to got  tool bar by extend Appcompatactivity so plz give any solution if u have??

Comment: @Sanjeev can you post your problem in another question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84065/discussion-between-sanjeev-and-rajesh-khadka).

Answer (score 1):

First, take any layout and in that, you put this toolbar.

use 27 SDK don't use Revision 28.0.0 Alphas version it has a bug I faced it.
if you wanna to use the latest SDK use version after alphas and like a beta.
use, after it's stable version, will come.

Answer (score 0):

If you use API level < 21 on device you should use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar from support library

Answer (score 0):

according to Java documentation  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:` is an `Runtime error` not `compileTimeError`.and `error` comes just of because your class which is able to be find while compiling but when program execute(Run Mode) this class not finded by `virtual machine`.So it is Clear now your Required class find while `compile()`but not while `execute()`.
enjoy your code:)-